# Shifting a character in string c++

Tags: c++, string

Hi here's the question: I want my user to enter row number and output an pyramid made of #'s such as

> ```
>    #
>   ###
>  #####   
> #######
> ```

... such as. And then when user inputs "1" my string will be:

> ```
>    1
>   ###    
>  #####   
> #######
> ```

My user inputs "1" again my string will be:

> ```
>    #
>   1##    
>  #####   
> #######
> ```

And this goes that well. At the end my string will be such as:

> ```
>    #
>   ###    
>  #####   
> ######1
> ```

and when my user inputs "2" string will be:

> ```
>    #
>   ###    
>  #####   
> #####1#
> ```

and "1" moves backwards. Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int move;
    cout << "Row Number: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << n << endl;
    string output="";
    string space;
    int location = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        space = "";
        for (int k = 0; k < (n - i); k++)
        {
            space = space + " ";
        }

        string str(i * 2 + 1, '#');
        output = output+space+str+"\n";
    }

    cout << output << endl;
    cout << output.size() << endl;

    basla:
    cout << "To Move Forward Enter 1, To Move Backward Enter 2: " << endl;
    cin >> move;
    switch (move)
    {
    case 1: location = location + 1;
        break;
    case 2: location = location - 1;
        break;
    }

    cout << location << endl;

    int locationcontrol = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++)
    {
        if (output[i] == '#')
        {
            locationcontrol = locationcontrol + 1;

            if (location = locationcontrol)
            {
                output[i] = '1';
                cout << output << endl;
                goto basla;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My code does this:

[code output](https://eksiup.com/p/4a242107sfwc)

How can i fix it?

Comment: Firstly, include the output as text in the question, not as link. Then, extract and provide a [mcve], preferably one that doesn't require any user input whatsoever to demonstrate the problem. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: why don't you use 2D array? and this line "if (location = locationcontrol) "is always true, use "if (location == locationcontrol) " instead

Comment: you locationcontrol  initialization "int locationcontrol = 0;"  should be before basla loop. Dont use goto!

Comment: This is how my teacher want i can't help it, user must input the row number and we must manipulate as string.

Comment: @samini oh thanks at least i solve one problem

Comment: The [mre] is for the purpose of this question.  After you learn the solution, you can adapt it to do whatever you and your teacher want.

Answer (score 0):

For your code, you have to reset the # that turned to 1 prior to the turn move. Thus, you have to convert the '1' in output back to '#'. For the loop, since you use a goto statement and you have to reset the 1s, you need to have a condition of when to go to that goto statement or when not to. This is your code with the fix. I added the reloop condition and the changing of the '1' back to '#'. Also, since you use a goto loop variables declaration should be outside of that goto loop. I don't know why the compiler that I used couldn't catch that redeclaration error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int move;
    cout << "Row Number: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << n << endl;
    string output="";
    string space;
    int location = 0;
    int locationcontrol;
    int reloop;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        space = "";
        for (int k = 0; k < (n - i); k++)
        {
            space = space + " ";
        }

        string str(i * 2 + 1, '#');
        output = output+space+str+"\n";
    }

    cout << output << endl;
    cout << output.size() << endl;

    basla:
    cout << "To Move Forward Enter 1, To Move Backward Enter 2: " << endl;
    cin >> move;
    switch (move)
    {
    case 1: location = location + 1;
        break;
    case 2: location = location - 1;
        break;
    }

    cout << location << endl;
    locationcontrol = 0;
    reloop = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++)
    {
        if (output[i] == '1') output[i] = '#';
        if (output[i] == '#')
        {
            locationcontrol = locationcontrol + 1;

            if (location == locationcontrol)
            {
                output[i] = '1';
                reloop = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( reloop == 1 ) {
      cout << output << endl;
      goto basla;
    }
}
```